# Event Stream via Gatling on POST endpoint

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I would like to ask if there is someone having experience doing assertions for event streaming service using Gatling against POST endpoint. Long story short, there is service similar how ChatGPT handles event streaming, so after POST request is being sent with parameters, response is received as event stream. In my case I would like if Gatling is capable in doing checks against such implemented interface as according to their SSE specification, it seems to be supported only for GET type of requests.

In general my goal for performance test to measure performance util first message is being returned from that event stream (e.g. {"message": "first message"}) and as part of that scenario not care for event stream to be finished. Is there a way with gatling to handle such a thing? Maybe some workaround how to deal with situation like that?

Open also for suggestions for JMeter solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: did you find a solution or how did you workaround this?

Comment: Answered on Gatling's community forum: https://community.gatling.io/t/llm-inference-completions-endpoint/8342/3